# openALPR integration into Appcelerator app via Hyperloop

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator, openalpr, hyperloop

I'm trying to integrate openALPR iOS module to Titanium app using Hyperloop from here: `https://github.com/yasirmturk/openalpr-swift`

I successfully installed it via cocoapods but now I'm stuck how to use it.
I have this code:

```
var openALPR = require("OpenALPRSwift");
var oaScanner = openALPR.OAScanner("eu");
```

But it throws error:

```
openALPR.OAScanner is not a function. (In 'openALPR.OAScanner(\"eu\")', 'openALPR.OAScanner' is undefined)
```

My Podfile is configured like this:

```
install! 'cocoapods',
     :integrate_targets => false
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

pre_install do |installer|
   Pod::Installer::Xcode::TargetValidator.send(:define_method, 
:verify_no_static_framework_transitive_dependencies) {}
end

post_install do |installer|
   installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
       phase_name = 'Headers'
    target.build_phases.each do |phase|
        if (phase.display_name.include? phase_name)
            target.build_phases.unshift(phase).uniq! unless 
target.build_phases.first == phase
           end
       end
   end
end 
target 'ALPRproject' do
   #pod 'OpenALPRSwift', '~> 1.0.0'
   pod 'OpenALPRSwift', :git => 
  'https://github.com/yasirmturk/openalpr-swift.git', :tag => 'v1.0.0'
end
```

Please help how to make it work.
Thanks for any response
Best Regards,
Marian